# Which HTTP code should return as status?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, api

I need to create REST API endpoint, and I am not sure which HTTP code to return as status.

Requirements are next:
- My API should accept URL as a parameter
- Make an API call to third-party service (use URL), and get a response
- Return response (content that fetched from third-party service)

In some cases, everything works fine. A call is made to external service, it returns content and status code 200.

But, sometimes there is no content and it returns 404. (Important, it is possible that content will be available in the future.)
From the perspective of my system, it is the regular situation.

Which HTTP code should I return?
[202](https://httpstatuses.com/202) - **Accepted**,
[204](https://httpstatuses.com/204) - **No content**,
[206](https://httpstatuses.com/206) - **Partial content**
or something else?

Comment: Server says _204, currently there is no response from URL that you passed, either send correct URL or try after sometime_

Comment: Why can't you return a 404 status code ?

Comment: @PapaStan it is a regular situation. It is possible that there is no content

Comment: @djm.im Requesting a page that doesn't exists through a http proxy do return a 404, even though the proxy did its job. This is the same situation.

Comment: Your service sounds like a simple proxy so what would make your service different to a proxy that would justify not to forward the 404 code like a proxy would do?

Comment: @t.niese it is not a simple proxy. The content that should be fetched is a part of a page (response) that will be returned.

Comment: Looks still like a proxy, one that transforms the data, but still a proxy like behavior. The user asks your API to get data from another service, and you either return this data wrapped in your own structure or you tell the user that there was currently no data available at that service and that's a `404`. I still can’t understand you concerns about using `404` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

> **404 Not Found**
>
> The requested resource could not be found but may be available in the future. Subsequent requests by the client are permissible.

In REST-API request and response should only work with current "call". If the content is currently not available it should return `404` status. And **It(`404`) is the exact status that should be returned.**

---

However, if you want to bend the rules, `204` status code seems more appropriate. I'm not recommending you to do this.

> **204 No Content**
>
> The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the actual resources, create a temporary one. Instead of returning a 201 (Created) HTTP response, you can issue a 202 (Accepted) response code. This informs the client that the request has been accepted and understood by the server, but the resource is not (yet) created.

[From: http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/](http://restcookbook.com/Resources/asynchroneous-operations/)

Comment: There is no actual ressource creation, the api just acts as a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You should return whatever the HTTP status code return by third party service unless your system is wrapping it up and processing it and changing the status.